# Why is Awk messing up my script variables

Tags: bash, awk, variable

I really don't know why my variables are getting messed up, but I suspect the cause is awk. I've condensed this problem down to a small script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

QUE_FILE="/mnt/drive4-4/private/queue2.txt"
t1="$(cat "$QUE_FILE")"
echo "$t1"
echo "============"
echo "$t1" | while read i; do
    a1="$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $1}')"
    a2="$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $2}')"
    echo "a1 $a1 - a2 $a2"
    combined="$a1 $a2 11111111111"
    echo "combined $combined"
done
```

And the output:

```
AA BB CC
DD EE
============
a1 AA - a2 BB
combined AA BB 11111111111
a1 DD - a2 EE
 11111111111EE
```

The last line there should be:

```
combined DD EE 11111111111
```

Comment: try replacing in your code `a2="$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $2}') | tr -d '\n' "`

Comment: Check for DOS-style (CRLF) line endings in your file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read A1 A2 REST; do echo -e "a1 $A1 - a2 $A2 \ncombined $A1 $A2 111111" ; done < /mnt/drive4-4/private/queue2.txt
```

The diference is that `awk` prints the *last on the row field* with 'end of line', while the `read AA BB CC` saves the particular fields without 'end of line'. The `REST` saves the third (if any) and all the next fields. In `echo -e` the `\n` breaks to the new line.